# How to setup Tailwind CSS with a React Microsoft Office Add-in created with Yeoman Generator?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, tailwind-css, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I created a Microsoft Office Add-in (for PowerPoint) with React using the Yeoman Generator as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview

Now, the question is how I can Tailwind to it.

Following the Tailwind installation documentation for Create React App (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) does not work.

I thought that installing Tailwind CSS as a PostCSS plugin could be a good idea, but I didn't get it to work.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skeletons generated by the yeoman generator uses webpack for bundling. It seems you need to set up [Setup Tailwind CSS with Webpack](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setup-tailwind-css-with-webpack-3458be3eb547).

Also you may find the [Tailwind not work as exepted with Webpack with JIT #4000](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4000) thread helpful.

Comment: I did not follow up on the proposed solution, but this seems to be the right approach. Thank you.

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

These were the steps needed to install it for me in an yeoman taskpane application with tailwind v3.3

1. Install dependencies:

`npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader postcss postcss-loader postcss-preset-env tailwindcss`

2. Add the following to the "rules" block in your webpack.config.js in the project root directory:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/i,
   include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
   use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
},
```

also add  `const path = require('path');` to the top of this file.

3. Add these lines to the top of your taskpane.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4. Remove `<link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` from your `taskpane.html` and add it as an import to the top of your `src/taskpane/index.tsx` like so:

```
import "./taskpane.css";
```

5. Create a `tailwind.config.js` in the root of your project

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

6. Add a postcss.config.js

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["postcss-preset-env", tailwindcss],
};
```

Done