# Setup TailwindCSS with Microsoft Office Add-in (React/ts) created with Yeoman Generator

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73561810/how-to-setup-tailwind-css-with-a-react-microsoft-office-add-in-created-with-yeom) post, but it's solution is broken, it seems outdated. I've also tried to follow [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setup-tailwind-css-with-webpack-3458be3eb547) tutorial, but it didn't work, same problem as above.

Where I feel I'm getting stuck is to find the entry point, since there is no `index.html` in this project.

Lastly I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/1c93938c1fe4f10d1e5b0532ae22e16a) tutorial, which is the approach I'm trying to get to work.

I think I'm getting configs conflict on `webpack.config.js`.

```js
// Tutorial config
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
}

// Pre existing config
const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};

// My merge attempt

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        // The same ...
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    // plugins: ... The same
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      static: {
        directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
      open: true,
      compress: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

On all approaches I got stuck on this point. When running `npm run build` I get this message:

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

The project structure is this (before TailwindCSS changes):

[image]

The project structure is this (afeter TailwindCSS changes):

[image]

Also this is my `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Hi, I worked a lot with SPFX so I assume that it is similar. The way I always used tailwind in this type of projects is by generating the output styles using the cli. and having either a concurrent script to build and watch the styles or run whenever you want.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#it-just-isn-t-working-properly

Comment: could you also add your tailwind config? I do not see that file in your folder structure.

Comment: This folder structure is from the project before installing tailwind css, I'll update with a folder structure after trying to set it up.

Comment: still would be useful to add the code from your talwind.config.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://dev.to/ivadyhabimana/setup-tailwind-css-in-a-react-project-configured-from-scratch-a-step-by-step-guide-2jc8) tutorial and finally made it work.

My final `webpack.config.js` is:

```js
const devCerts = require('office-addin-dev-certs')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const urlDev = 'https://localhost:3000/'
const urlProd = 'https://compass-esg.jgp.com.br/'

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions()
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert }
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === 'development'
  const config = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
      polyfill: ['core-js/stable', 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
      vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'core-js'],
      taskpane: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './src/taskpane/index.tsx',
        './src/taskpane/taskpane.html',
      ],
      commands: './src/commands/commands.ts',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
      filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.html', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'ts-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'html-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'assets/[name][ext][query]',
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          include: /node_modules\/react-dom/,
          use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: 'assets/*',
            to: 'assets/[name][ext][query]',
          },
          {
            from: 'manifest*.xml',
            to: '[name]' + '[ext]',
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content
              } else {
                return content
                  .toString()
                  .replace(new RegExp(urlDev, 'g'), urlProd)
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'taskpane.html',
        template: './src/taskpane/taskpane.html',
        chunks: ['taskpane', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'commands'],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ['es6-promise', 'Promise'],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      open: true,
      liveReload: true,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      server: {
        type: 'https',
        options:
          env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined
            ? options.https
            : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  }

  return config
}
```